# Merging iPhoto libraries

Tags: photos.app, macos

I am currently running MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014) with Yosemite 10.10.2

For iPhoto I have a current library and 2 older libraries and now wish to:

- Merge all three into one iPhoto library
- Remove duplicates

How can I accomplish this?